# How to extract the 2nd column of a 1x2 index in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, indexing, multi-index

I am exploring the Spaceship Titanic dataset in kaggle ([linked here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/spaceship-titanic)) and got stuck.

**What I want to do:** plot in a pretty pie chart the ratio of passengers that made it to their destination

**The result:** I managed to get [an ugly pie chart going](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Feu.png)

**What I want to do next:** Remove the planet names and just have the `True` and `False` values in the pie chart. The planet name will be a title.

**DATA:**

```
MultiIndex([( '55 Cancri e', False),
            ( '55 Cancri e', True),
            ( 'PSO J317.5-22', False),
            ( 'PSO J317.5-22', True),
            ( 'TRAPPIST-1e', False),
            ( 'TRAPPIST-1e', True),
            names =['Destination,'Transported'])
```

**Where I got stuck:** I cannot seem to get just the `Col[1]` values.

`print(Survival_Destination_table.index[0:2])`, gives me the first two rows for '55 Cancri e'
`print(Survival_Destination_table.index[0:2][1])`, gives me the second row ('55 Cancri e', True)
`print(Survival_Destination_table.index[0:2][1][1])`, gives me the `Col[1]` of second row i.e. `True`

BUT it's just a single value and I can't exactly set that as the plot label. Please help.

**Code for plotting** (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
axes[0].pie(Survival_Destination_table.values[0:2], labels = Survival_Destination_table.index[0:2], autopct = '%1.1f%%', radius=1)
axes[1].pie(Survival_Destination_table.values[2:4], labels = Survival_Destination_table.index[2:4], autopct = '%1.1f%%', radius=1)
axes[2].pie(Survival_Destination_table.values[4:6], labels = Survival_Destination_table.index[4:6], autopct = "%1.1f%%", radius=1)
plt.plot()
```

[My kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/potatomato64/spaceshiptitanic)

Comment: Why don't you `.reset_index()` first, then get the columns you want for plotting.

Comment: OH HEY! Thanks! I didn't know that method existed. I quickly tested it and it decoupled the indices into two columns. I will play around with it in my next coding run maybe tomorrow